# HTTPS url not redirecting properly (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I have a website domain that does not contain www. and I am struggling to get proper redirects using HTTPS.

HTTP requests do get properly redirected
*i.e. http://www.website.com -> https://website.com which is what I want*

However HTTPS request do not get properly redirected which results in a duplicate page.
*i.e. https://www.website.com -> https://www.website.com but should be going to https://website.com*

I do believe it is an issue with my Nginx sites_enabled script but I cannot figure it out.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.com www.website.com;
        return 301 $scheme://website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name website.com www.website.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/website.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/website.key;     

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/website/django_webApp/webApp;
        }
        
        location /staticfiles/ {
                root /home/website/django_webApp/webApp;
        }
        
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think through the logic. Right now you have a redirect from HTTP on either website.com or [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) to http at website.com, followed by a block listening at both of those domains. If you're on port 80, you don't want to redirect to `$scheme`, you want to redirect to https.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.com www.website.com;
        return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;
}
```

If you're at https://www.website.com, you want to redirect to website.com

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.website.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/website.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/website.key;     
        return 301 $scheme://website.com.com$request_uri;
}
```

Followed by your last "real" server block:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name website.com;

        // everything else
}

This unforunately could result in more than one redirect, but is the easiest code to understand. More options are discussed [over here](https://serverfault.com/questions/258378/remove-www-and-redirect-to-https-with-nginx).
```

Comment: thank you! just note for the second block, make sure you add the ssl certificate info or it won't work.

Comment: @Charlie oh yes, of course, that was my oversight. I'll edit my answer to include that.